# How to add/remove objects with time in Three.js

Tags: javascript, time, timer, three.js

I want to add and remove objects with a period. For example, i have an array which includes 50 objects. I want to add the object with a period while removing the previous one, like creating an object stream. First i tried with setTimeout and setInterval functions but they didn't work (both inside and outside render function). Then i tried this;

```
function render(){
    controls.update(clock.getDelta());
    renderer.render( scene, camera);
    i = i+1;
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        if (i % 300 == 0){
            remove(lights);
        }
        else
        {   scene.add(lights[(i/2)]);
        }
    }
}
```

It works but it does not start adding process with first object. I also tried getElapsedtime() instead of iterating i, but this time it only adds the first object. Is there any more effective time controlled method that i can use for this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
var spotOn = true;
window.setInterval(function(){spot()},milliseconds);

function spot() {
    var i;
    if(spotOn) {
        for(i = 0; i < lights.length; ++i) {
            scene.add(lights[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i < lights.length; ++i) {
            scene.remove(lights[i]);
        }
    }
    spotOn = !spotOn;
}

function render(){
    renderer.render( scene, camera);
}
```